# Loading a dxp file which has a parametrized information links using Automation Services

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to load an analysis file in Automation Services which has a Parametrized Information link. Currently when I load the analysis to Automation Services it's throwing an error as there is no parameter that's been passed to the IL.

Is there a way to modify/alter the XML code to pass the parameter to the Information Link.

Consider the below example where the analysis open with the error "No value was provided for parameter NumberList". Any idea to implement this approach would be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<as:Job xmlns:as="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation">
  <as:Tasks>
    <OpenAnalysisFromLibrary 
xmlns="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation.tasks">
      <as:Title>Open Analysis from Library</as:Title>
      <AnalysisPath>/Library/Docs/Automation</AnalysisPath>


    </OpenAnalysisFromLibrary>
  </as:Tasks>
</as:Job>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally done this, but according to the [Automation Services manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire-automation-services/7.6.0/doc/pdf/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_7.6.0_user_manual.pdf), page 24:

> [When setting up a Load Analysis task] you can use a configuration block to configure the initial state of the analysis file that you want to open, such as applying a bookmark, or setting a filter to the analysis before it is opened.

some general info on configuraion blocks:

> In the following example, the first two lines are parameter assignments, the following lines are configuration statements:

```
Region = "West";
Acme.Limits = { 10, 100, 1000 };
SetPage(pageTitle = "Overview");
ApplyBookmark(bookmarkName = "UserRegionOnly");
SetFilter(tableName = "Table 1", columnName = "Column 1", values = { "A", "B" });
SetMarking(tableName = "Table 2", whereClause = "Gender = 'Male' AND GeekFactor = 'High'");
```

check the [TIBCO Community wiki](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire) for more info on creating config blocks. protip: **DON'T FORGET THE SEMICOLONS** :) very easy to omit those and then get frustrated when it doesn't work. each individual assignment needs a semicolon, just like the example.